# "To sign into this application the account must be added to the domain.com directory"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to login to our Azure account from Powershell.
I installed the proper module but am unable to get passed the following error:

> PS C:> Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred Add-AzureAccount
>
> AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added
>   to the domain.com directory. Trace ID:
>   ef487122-88d6-4e36-8421-4434806041d2 Correlation ID:
>   a1ea0ee1-b278-4241-bc48-e213ecd47b27 Timestamp: 2014-11-04 09:46:02Z:
>   The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount

I'm new to Azure so I have no idea what or where is this "domain.com" directory.
I also failed to find anything even remotely related over the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WORKAROUND:

Use the certificate method instead.
Works instantly without a hitch.

Comment: Yes, but this only less you access the older "services management" (ASM), you can not use any commands that depend on the newer "resource management" (ARM)

Answer (score 6):

Login at https://manage.windowsazure.com/ and select `Subscriptions` > `Manage subscriptions\directory`. Each subscription is associated with a particular Azure Active Directory. Select `Active Directory` from the list of services on the left menu. Open up directory you are interested in. The list of `users` will say if it is `sourced from` a `Microsoft account` or `Windows Azure Active Directory`. You can only automate signing in to a Azure AD account.

[image]

You can create an account by selecting `add user` and `New user in your organization`.

[image]

I wish I could sign in from the command line without a UI prompt using my `Microsoft account`. I'm not sure why it is setup this way. But yes, you must currently use a domain account to sign in automatically.

Comment: It's not as simple as it just being 'Source: Azure Active Directory'. I had a login that I needed to click 'Personal Account' to log into even though it was shown as 'Azure Active Directory'. When it's a 'Personal Account' it can still show as being AD :-/

Answer (score 3):

Try using the cmdlet "add-azureaccount" without any parameters, you will get a simple login screen popup where you can enter your azure credentials.

Comment: This worked for me. All guides and tutorials tell you to use the variable $credentials, but if you do it like this, you get a microsoft login screen, which works.

Comment: Does this 'block' the rest of the script from continuing automatically? What's the recommended approach to do this correctly to avoid running the rest of the script if you exit out without a successful login.