# Failed to retrieve Azure auth token. Account must be added to the directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-management-api

I have an Active Directory object in Azure that has a native client application.
The application has all the necessary permissions to be accessed by the Service Management API.
[image: App permissions]

In the AD directory, I have 2 users added. One is the account I was logged in as when I created the directory object. This account was added automatically when the directory was created. The other is one that I manually added after creating the directory object.

So, in the example below, Account 2 was the account I was logged in as when creating the directory. Account 1 I added manually.
[image: Example]

When I try to retrieve an access token from the oauth2 endpoint with Account 2 credentials, I get the error:

```
AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the REDACTED directory.
```

The account is clearly added to the directory, however.
Furthermore, when I use the credentials for Account 1, I am able to successfully authenticate.
The only things I'm changing in my script are the username and password. The client ID and tenant ID remain the same.

Why am I getting the error above when the account I am using is clearly a user of the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a different thread.
If I'm understanding it correctly, it seems like automated sign-in can only be done from an account sourced from Azure Active Directory, and not from a Microsoft account.

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732711/to-sign-into-this-application-the-account-must-be-added-to-the-domain-com-direc)

Answer (score 0):

you can log-in with account2 also. You need to provide the directory name in the Sign-in context as the input. Accordingly, configure your "Startup.Auth.cs" in App_Start.

Account1 has the directory name or the custom domain name in the username with the help of which the Azure log-in gets you signed-in against. But, with account2, you have Microsoft account directory where your application is not registered. 
Hence, you get the error.

Use [this](https://github.com/dushyantgill/VipSwapper/tree/master/CloudSense) link for better concept. This sample code has used the sign-in for Azure AD user as well as Microsoft account user as in your case.