# To sign into this application the account must be added to the <TenantID> directory

Tags: java, azure, certificate, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I am trying to authenticate and app and get bearer token for further use. I get the error which is title of this thread.

Another thread describes same thing except that my code is in Java. the workaround is to use certificate method.
["To sign into this application the account must be added to the domain.com directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732711/to-sign-into-this-application-the-account-must-be-added-to-the-domain-com-direc)

Can someone please describe detailed steps for this workaround :- certificate method
Or how can i fix the below code with any other method
Or is any other method to achieve this whole task

Here is my code

```
private final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/OAuth2/Authorize";
private final static String CLIENT_ID = "<Client_Id>";
private final static String CLIENT_SECRET = "<Secret>";

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in))) {

        String username = CLIENT_ID;
        String password = CLIENT_SECRET;

        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                "https://graph.microsoft.com", CLIENT_ID, username, password,
                null);
        result = future.get();

    }
    finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
```

}

I have registered my app in AAD app registration. The Client_Id is App Id and Secret is a key in the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use certificate credentials to authenticate your app, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials#register-your-certificate-with-azure-ad).

**Steps**:

1.[Uploading the certificate file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials#uploading-the-certificate-file)

2.[Updating the application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials#updating-the-application-manifest)

**Code sample**(it uses C#, you could refer):
[Authenticating to Azure AD in daemon apps with certificates](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential)

It also shows how you can [create a self-signed certificate](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential#create-a-self-signed-certificate) using the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` Powershell command. You can also take advantage and use the [app creation scripts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/blob/master/AppCreationScripts/AppCreationScripts.md) to create the certificates, compute the thumbprint, and so on.

Comment: Looks like if I use certificate, I have to use ClientAssertion. Can you please tell me what do I need to change in the above code? How do I generate assertion string?

Comment: @user10360768 I could just give you a [sample for c#](https://github.com/TomSunGit/AzureADDemo#use-client-assertion-to-get-access-tokens-from-azure-ad).

Answer (score 1):

In case, you want to make the code work in it's current form without any workaround, check for following things -

1. Make sure you have the **correct tenantId GUID** specified in the first line of code.

   Steps to get tenantid -

   Login to Azure Portal, Navigate to your Azure AD, Go to properties like in screenshot below and Directory ID should give you the GUID.

[image]

```
 private final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/OAuth2/Authorize";
```

2. Make sure that Username you are using, is for a user that belongs to your AzureAD tenant.

   One possible reason could be if you're using a Microsoft account like xyz@outlook.com or hotmail.com etc. Try using an account that is created in this Azure AD like xyz@yourtenantdomain.onmicrosoft.com or any other verified domain that your tenant uses.

`Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", CLIENT_ID, username, password, null);`

Comment: TenantId was always correct. I am using app to authenticate, may be I need to change my code. Do you know what change i need to make?

Comment: ok got it. Check these things: A - You didn't confirm about the user, does the user belong to your AD or is it a Microsoft Account, see point 2 in my answer above. B - From a code standpoint, you're setting password = CLIENT_SECRET, should it be the password for this user instead? are you following one of the samples, if you are check there. C - Have you given admin consent on Microsoft Graph API from portal by clicking Grant Permissions?